# The events don't see the listeners in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, events, frameworks, listener

I have used event and listeners before but now I'm trying to use event and listeners but the event don't see the listeners as the code below

The event

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class teste
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;


    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [new PrivateChannel('channel-name')];
    }
}
```

and it is the listener of the event

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\teste;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class testl
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }


    public function handle(teste $event)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the eventProviderService

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $listen = [
        // Registered::class => [
        //     SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        // ],
        'App\Events\teste' => [
            'App\Listeners\testl'
        ],


    ];
```

and the code to call the event is

```
Route::get("test100" , function(){
        $Event = event(new \App\Events\teste());
        dd($Event);
    });
```

and after all, there is no output when i use function dd() to check the output it's nothing it's empty array don't contain null or any thing 
and when i use function dd() in the listener to check if the event see the listener or no, the result was nothing

Comment: Don't share image of code, share the actual code

Comment: I've only got a couple of suggestions right now as i can't see anything obviously wrong. 1) Remove `return [new PrivateChannel('channel-name')];` from your event (if the channel does not exist it could cause a problem) 2) Run `composer dump-autoload` just to be sure that your Listener class has been registered for autoloading.

Comment: I have solved the problem by removing the cash files from directory bootstrap and run composer install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `Event`s and `Listener`s to function, you need to have mapped which `Listner`s respond to a given `Event`. In Laravel, this is handled within the `EventServiceProvider`

The example below is taken from the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/events#registering-events-and-listeners):

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\OrderShipped' => [
        'App\Listeners\SendShipmentNotification',
    ],
];
```

Any number of `Listener`s can react to a given `Event`

**EDIT:** Also, make sure that the namespacing is correct for your application

Comment: I know and i'm sure that i make all that

Comment: I have edited the post and added some codes if you can help now

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem by removing the cash files form the directory bootstrap and running composer install

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same issue despite having all the configs in the right places including the namespacing.

Normally, the job queues run in a separate async process and if you introduce a new Event/Listener they may not be recognised until you restart the queue.

```
php artisan queue:restart
```